# How to get a certain data in one row on

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

is it possible to get a certain data under one row in sql?

At the moment my result is:

```
name                        Month_Number    Month   YEAR    Total_Amount Total_Retailfee Total_Transactions
Spar Group                  1               January 2013    46928270.04  269477.0855     100445
Shoprite Checkers Pty Ltd   1               January 2013    83228663.71  290345.517      91282
Pick n Pay (Pty) Ltd        1               January 2013    78518522.5   590395.6488     210117
Pep                         1               January 2013    185792113.3  1847361.334     457374
```

But I need it like this:

```
name       Month_Number Month   YEAR Description        
Spar Group 1            January 2013 Total_Amount       46928270.04
                                     Total_Retailfee    269477.0855 
                                     Total_Transactions 100445
```

Comment: try `SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE name = 'Spar Group'`?

Comment: Sorry the result I need didnt show properly, I basically need all four those names but I need Total amount, total_Retailfee and total_transactions underneath each other with the row name as description and next to each their amount.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this -

```
SELECT
  name, Month_Number, Month, YEAR,
  CONCAT_WS(
    '\r\n',
    CONCAT('Total_Amount=',Total_Amount),
    CONCAT('Total_Retailfee=',Total_Retailfee),
    CONCAT('Total_Transactions=',Total_Transactions)
  ) AS description
FROM
  table;
```

[CONCAT_WS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) function.

Comment: I have chanaged query.

Comment: USE [PAYAT]
SELECT c.name,month(DateCreated) AS Month_Number, 
   YEAR(DateCreated) AS YEAR,
       sum(t.amount) as Total_Amount, sum (t.Retailfee) AS Total_Retailfee,
       count(t.RecID) as Total_Transactions
FROM dbo.tblPay@transactions t (nolock)
left outer join dbo.tblPay@company c (nolock)
ON t.RetailId = c.RecID
GROUP BY c.name,month(DateCreated),YEAR(DateCreated)
ORDER BY Month(DateCreated) - This is my script I have at the moment

Comment: i agree with Devart query.@user3110565 you should always tell how you got such result in first place.it can be corrected from the very beginning.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT column_1, column_3, column_5 FROM myTable WHERE column_1 = "some_value"
```

This will select only certain values in that row.

Answer (score 0):

I would first like to mention that if this is for presentation in a web interface or report, you may be able to do a much simpler grouping query with summation and then simply move the data pieces to appear where they need to be. For example, you could begin a new HTML row after [Total_Amount], and insert 4 empty cells, then the next subtotal, etc, creating the desired tabular structure.

```
-- it appears this query contains everything you are asking for, but not using the same 'tabular structure.'
SELECT
    name
    ,MONTH([MyDate]) AS [MonthNumber]
    ,DATENAME(MONTH, [MyDate]) AS [MONTH]
    ,YEAR([MyDate]) AS [YEAR]   
    ,SUM(Amount) AS [Total_Amount]
    ,SUM(Retailfee) AS [Total_Retailfee] -- move down one row
    ,SUM(Transactions) AS [Total_Transactions] -- move down two rows
FROM #temp
GROUP BY
     name
    ,MONTH([MyDate])
    ,DATENAME(MONTH, [MyDate])
    ,YEAR([MyDate]
```

It appears that you wish to have three rows returned in your query for each [name] and [MONTH] combination in your data set. If so, here is a solution using a setup to create some sample data and a derived table to extract this as desired:

```
-- I find that providing example data help to get more accurate results for some queries
CREATE TABLE #temp (
     name VARCHAR(20)
    ,MyDate DATE
    ,Amount DECIMAL(8,4)
    ,Retailfee DECIMAL(8,4)
    ,Transactions DECIMAL(8,4)
);

-- no idea what these values actually mean so the data may not make sense.
INSERT #temp VALUES ('Spar Group','01/01/2013',1000.00,163.55,200.00)
INSERT #temp VALUES ('Spar Group','01/02/2013',40.00,0.11,2.00)
INSERT #temp VALUES ('Spar Group','01/03/2013',299.99,35.00,33.00)
INSERT #temp VALUES ('Spar Group','02/03/2013',145.99,0.00,7.00)
INSERT #temp VALUES ('Shoprite','01/01/2013',22.99,0.00,8.00)
INSERT #temp VALUES ('Shoprite','01/02/2013',149.95,16.60,11.50)

SELECT
     name
    ,[MonthNumber]
    ,[MONTH]
    ,[YEAR]
    ,[Category]
    ,[CategoryTotal]
FROM (
    -- select the first row for each [name],[month] group
    SELECT
        name
        ,MONTH([MyDate]) AS [MonthNumber]
        ,DATENAME(MONTH, [MyDate]) AS [MONTH]
        ,YEAR([MyDate]) AS [YEAR]   
        ,'Total_Amount' AS [Category]
        ,SUM(Amount) AS [CategoryTotal]
    FROM #temp
    GROUP BY
         name
        ,MONTH([MyDate])
        ,DATENAME(MONTH, [MyDate])
        ,YEAR([MyDate])

    UNION ALL
    -- select the second row for each [name],[month] group
    SELECT
        name
        ,MONTH([MyDate]) AS [MonthNumber]
        ,DATENAME(MONTH, [MyDate]) AS [MONTH]
        ,YEAR([MyDate]) AS [YEAR]   
        ,'Total_Retailfee' AS [Category]
        ,SUM(Retailfee) AS [CategoryTotal]
    FROM #temp
    GROUP BY
         name
        ,MONTH([MyDate])
        ,DATENAME(MONTH, [MyDate])
        ,YEAR([MyDate])

    UNION ALL
    -- select the third row for each [name],[month] group
    SELECT
        name
        ,MONTH([MyDate]) AS [MonthNumber]
        ,DATENAME(MONTH, [MyDate]) AS [MONTH]
        ,YEAR([MyDate]) AS [YEAR]   
        ,'Total_Transactions' AS [Category]
        ,SUM(Transactions) AS [CategoryTotal]
    FROM #temp
    GROUP BY
         name
        ,MONTH([MyDate])
        ,DATENAME(MONTH, [MyDate])
        ,YEAR([MyDate])
) AS T
ORDER BY
     name, [MONTH], [YEAR]
    ,CASE
        WHEN [Category]='Total_Amount' THEN 1
        WHEN [Category]='Total_Retailfee' THEN 2
        ELSE 3
     END
```